# How to deal with API raises in general but more specifically from Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

so I'm fairly new into this thing exactly, which are the errors an API can raise, and how you can adjust your code to that.

So for example I'm using the Twitter gem, and if I'd like to favorite a tweet, then delete the tweet my page goes to a 500 and I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No status found with that ID.)
```

The thing that I'm wondering is how do I write code that can deal with these errors. So say I give an array of 2 ids, where the first doesn't work and the other don't. Ideally I'd like it to skip the first one. However with the current situation it would stop all together.

There are problem some reading I can do, but I'm not sure what this is called.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not very clear but this should give you some direction I think: http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would write something to handle the exception. An example would be:

```
begin
  go_get_tweet 
rescue Twitter::BadRequest => e
  logger.error e.message
  # ...code to continue gracefully
rescue Twitter::TimeoutError => e
  do_something_that_retries
rescue => e
  logger.error "..."
end
```

In this really rushed example it would match to a couple of specific exceptions and also to any that you have not specified as a catch-all.